# Why does this read input before printing?

Tags: rust

I'm having some problems with some basic I/O stuff. Specifically, the text "Please enter your name" is written to the output **after** I type in my name and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    print!("Please enter your name: ");

    let mut name = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
        Ok(_) => println!(""),
        Err(err) => println!("Could not parse input: {}", err)
    }

    println!("Hello, {}!", name.trim());
}
```

gives the following output:

```
Compiling chat v0.1.0 (file:///home/marcus/dev/rust/chat)
  Running `target/debug/chat`
marcus
Please enter your name: 
Hello, marcus!
```

Where the first "marcus" was entered by me. Why won't the program print "Please enter your name" before waiting for input?

---

Is it possible to "do nothing" if a returned `Result` is `Ok`? In the example, `Ok()` means that I have saved the input in the variable name. That's great. But what do I do with `Ok() =>` in this case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Why won't the program print "Please enter your name" before waiting for input?

Well, it *did*.  It's just that, for performance reasons, standard output is buffered.  The write completed, but it was only writing to memory.  If you want it to actually display to the user, you have to trigger a flush.  This can be done either by writing a newline, or by doing it explicitly:

```
io::Write::flush(&mut io::stdout()).expect("flush failed!");

// If you "use" `io::Write`...
io::stdout().flush().expect("flush failed!");
```

> Also, is it possible to "do nothing" if a returned Result is Ok?

Sure.  Just... do nothing.

```
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
    Ok(_) => { /* nothing */ },
    Err(err) => println!("Could not parse input: {}", err)
}
```

The relevant requirement here is that all arms in a `match` have to have the same result type.  In the case of `println!`, it results in a `()`; aside from an empty block (or another function that returns `()`), you can just use a literal:

```
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
    Ok(_) => (),
    Err(err) => println!("Could not parse input: {}", err)
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention `if let Err(err) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) { println!("Could not parse input: {}", err); }`.

Answer (score 26):

This is explained on the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print!.html) for `print!`. Since `print!` does not emit a newline and stdout is line-buffered, you won't see any output. You can manually flush stdout:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

print!("Please enter your name: ");
io::stdout().flush();
```

For your second question you can always return unit explicitly:

```
Ok(_) => (),
```

So your program becomes:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    print!("Please enter your name: ");
    io::stdout().flush();

    let mut name = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(err) => println!("Could not parse input: {}", err)
    }

    println!("Hello, {}!", name.trim());
}
```

As @Veedrac pointed out in their (now deleted) comment, you can use an [`if let expression`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#if-let-expressions) in place of the `match` on the result of `read_line`:

```
if let Err(err) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
    println!("Could not parse input: {}", err)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I had actually tried that but got some error because it didn't recognize the `.flush()` function. Turns out I had missed the last part `use std::io::{self, Write};`. Would you care to elaborate what the `{self, Write}` means? I can't seem to find it in the documentation

Answer (score -1):

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    print!("Please enter your name: ");
    let _ = io::stdout().flush();
    // your io code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers with only code are usually not very well received as they don't *explain* anything. Additionally, this question already has two answers that already make use of `flush`, so it's unclear what benefit this new answer brings. Please [edit] your answer to describe the changes and how it differs from existing answers.

Comment: Ignoring an error is fairly uncommon in Rust. This answer would be further improved by detailing why that decision is a good idea for this case.