# Different output of printing in rust and python

Tags: rust

I am trying rust and i want to create one line print for my timer.

Python code which i want to write in rust:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(61):
    print(i, end="\r")
    sleep(1)
```

This code prints the seconds in one line, thereby updating second count in line

I tried do this with rust:

```
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    for i in 0..61 {
        print!("{}\r", i);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

Rust script doesn't print anything, but python script prints second and updates it:
When you just run it

```
$ python script.py
0
```

When it's running for 1 second

```
$ python script.py
1
```

When it's running for 2 second

```
$ python script.py
0
```

I tried remove "\r" from line in rust code and now it waits 60 seconds and after prints numbers in one line from 0 to 61: `0123456789...%`

I don't see difference between python and rust code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this read input before printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993744/why-does-this-read-input-before-printing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust `stdout` is buffered meaning that you need to flush it if you are not printing newlines and want it to output something.

This is how you would write it:

```rust
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    for i in 0..61 {
        print!("{}\r", i);
        match io::stdout().flush() {
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(_) => std::process::exit(1)
        }
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use `println!()` macro as it handles flushing and line feed control characters for you.

Comment: @IvanC I tried using `println` and it prints each of the new ints on a new line instead of replacing the old int.

Answer (score 0):

try println

```
for i in 1..10{
  println!("{}",i);
  sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
}
```